# efficient way to align divs side by side?

Tags: html, css

Whats the best way to align 3, 4 or even 5 divs side by side? with a space in between each one separating them apart.

I have tried googling this but there seems to be so many different answers out there that just seem too use case dependent (i.e if its for 2 divs or 3 divs etc) im asking whats the best way to do this for any number of divs?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All answers given here are excellent and they are the efficient way. But I tried to make them easier for you.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="apnd">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
  <div>Nine</div>
  <div>Ten</div>
  <div>Eleven</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#apnd div { 
        height: 100px; 
        width: 100px; 
        border: 1px solid red; 
        margin-left: 5px; 
        float: left; /*Here you can also use display: inline-block instead of float:left*/
        background: orange; 
}
```

Comment: http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block has a good walk-through of different techniques.

You could also consider using the grid from a responsive design framework such as Foundation - http://foundation.zurb.com

Answer (score 4):

Another option: http://jsfiddle.net/brandondurham/Tht3N/

```
<div id="row">
    <div>One</div><div>Two</div><div>Three</div><div>One</div><div>Two</div><div>Three</div><div>One</div><div>Two</div><div>Three</div><div>One</div><div>Two</div><div>Three</div><div>One</div><div>Two</div><div>Three</div><div>One</div><div>Two</div><div>Three</div><div>One</div><div>Two</div><div>Three</div>
</div>

#row {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#row > div {
    background: lightblue;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
#row > div + div {
    margin-left: 10px
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please just walk me through whats going on here? im not familiar with this style of CSS. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Is there something like this:

```
div.container { display:table; border-spacing:{your-space}px; }
div.container > div { display:table-cell; }
```

in your "so many different answers" set?

For today it is the most reliable way of making horizontal row of block elements.

Until CSS WG will accept http://www.terrainformatica.com/w3/flex-layout/flex-layout.htm :)

Comment: Hi, I dont really understand what your trying to do there, can you please provide a very simple code example of 3 divs aligned next to each other? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div {
float:left
margin-left:20px; //or whatever you want
}

div:first-child {
margin-left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/equalizeCols