# Inline alignment of divs (side-by-side) with a little space in between

Tags: css, html, word-wrap, alignment

I'm going to put 4 divs in a 100% width container side-by-side.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765848/efficient-way-to-align-divs-side-by-side) and it was useful.

But my problem is that while using that solution, divs are stick to each other, but I need a little margin/space among them.

For example support a child div like this:

```
<div class="introwrapper" 
     style="width:25%;height:100%; float:left; margin-left:5px;">
</div>
```

Actually, I want to make these 4 divs placed side-by-side and make a space of 5 pixels between them, for the rest of the space remaining, make their width equal and the make the sum of widths of all these 4 divs and all 3 5px margins 100%.

How can I make this type of alignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

(Please note that sx.png is a 10x10 px transparent placeholder).

```
<div style="height: 160px; width: 100%; box-sizing:border-box; display:table;">
                <div class="introwrapper" style="height:100%; width:25%;display:table-cell;">a</div>
                <img src="../_imgs/sx.png" />
                <div class="introwrapper" style="height:100%; width:25%;display:table-cell;">b</div>
                <img src="../_imgs/sx.png" />
                <div class="introwrapper" style="height:100%; width:25%;display:table-cell;">c</div>
                <img src="../_imgs/sx.png" />
                <div class="introwrapper" style="height:100%; width:25%;display:table-cell;">d</div>                
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the confusion. I though a technique would work, that I have used frequently for centring objects, however it didn't.

Unfortunately, the only thing I can think of right now is an additional layer of containers/wrappers.

Essentialy:

- Container `width: 100%`

  - Inner container: `width: 25%;`

    - Your object div `padding-right: 5px;` no width. It will be set automatically through the `display: block`property, that a div has by default.

Comment: Unfortunately the 4th div sits down into second line:<div style="height: 160px; width: 100%; margin: 0 15px 0 5px;box-sizing:border-box;">
    <div class="introwrapper" style="width:25%;height:100%;float:left; margin-right:5px;">a</div>
    <div class="introwrapper" style="width:25%;height:100%;float:left;margin-right:5px;">b</div>
    <div class="introwrapper" style="width:25%;height:100%;float:left;margin-right:5px;">c</div>
    <div class="introwrapper" style="width:25%;height:100%;float:left;">d</div>
   </div>

Comment: I know ... its pretty late over here. Made some thinking error. I'm trying to figure it out right now.

Comment: I understand. Actually it is now 2:40 AM here in Tehran :)

Comment: @Farshid See the updated answer. Unfortunately the first option didn't work out.

Comment: Dear Tim, thanks for your kind help. The working solution is brought as answer.